# Traduction de « attitude adjustment + give » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

Dans un [échange](https://youtu.be/mSOSkxTv1G0?t=36s) entre deux personnages d'une série télé :

> **Julie**: — Oh yes, congratulations on selling out your people to a bunch
>   of nightcrawlers.(slap)
>  **Diana**: — You need an *[attitude](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/attitude)
>   [adjustment](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/adjustment)* my dear, and it will be my pleasure to *[give](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/give) it to you*. (To
>   Steven) Put her aboard my ship, if you can manage that.
>
> [ *[V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_%28The_Final_Battle%29), The Final Battle*, p. 1 (1984) ]

Je cherche à rendre l'*« attitude adjustment* » de concert avec le « *give it to you* » :

> Ma chère, vous avez besoin d'un ... [et] il me fera plaisir de ...

ou l'équivalent, de manière à ce que ça soit usuel et se dise aisément. Est-ce qu'on traduit  littéralement par « *ajustement d'attitude* » et peut-on « *donner* » ça à quelqu'un; n'est-ce pas là un truc qu'on dirait dans le domaine maritime ou en aéronautique ?

Comment: pourquoi pas quelquechose dans le style "**Tu as besoin [d'un recadrement/d'être recadrée] ma chère, et je me ferai un plaisir de le faire**" ?

Comment: @Random Le problème étant que *recadrer*, comme *synergie*, *proactif* et *solutionner*, n'existent **que** dans l'univers de l'entreprise. L'idée est la bonne, je suis d'accord, mais c'est le registre de vocabulaire qui ne correspond pas. Si ça avait été une scène de *Caméra café*, oui, pourquoi pas...

Comment: @RomainVALERI Je ne vois pas de notion d’entreprise personnellement, on peut aussi **recadrer** un enfant. Pour moi, cela implique juste qu'il y ait des limites, et qu'il faille rappeler à la personne où elles sont.

Comment: @Random J'ai moi aussi entendu dire *recadrer un enfant*, mais c'est un des aspects de l'extension rampante du domaine de la gestion aux autres domaines de la vie. J'ai également déjà entendu dire qu'on devait *gérer son capital santé*, et ça s'explique par le même genre de glissement sémantique (et idéologique ?) assez facheux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the notion, in English, of getting and giving an [attitude] adjustment comes from giving (performing/doing) and getting (having [it] performed/having [it] done/submitting to) a chiropractic adjustment, which leads me to the verbs ‘faire’ or even ‘effectuer’ for the “giving” side of a chiropractic adjustment in French.

As you point out, a literal translation (ajustement d'attitude) would conflict with some pre-existing meanings in other domains.  I feel, however, that the word “attitude” is important enough in fully capturing this notion to justify keeping it, and the best way, I think, to accomplish this is by replacing “ajustement” with “changement” and using the verb “effectuer” with it:

> Ma chère, vous avez besoin d’un changement d’attitude [et] il/cela me
>   fera plaisir de l’effectuer.

To the extent that “[changement d’attitude](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=en&langTo=fr&q=attitude+adjustment&langTot=en-fr)” might still have meanings in the domains you mentioned (as well as in the domain of sociology), I’d suggest using the following verbal construction to translate “attitude adjustment”:  “[devoir/falloir/avoir besoin de] [changer d’attitude](http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/an+attitude+adjustment)” and although I think “effectuer” works well with “changement, with this verbal version I’d use instead the verb “s’occuper”:

> Ma chère, vous avez besoin de (vous devez/il faut) changer
>   d’attitude/[votre
>   attitude](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=fr&langTo=en&q=changer+ton+attitude&langTot=fr-en)
>   [et] il/cela me fera plaisir de m’en occuper.

(The only way that I see to use the notion of “give”/ “donner” in this exchange (regardless of how you end up translating “attitude adjustment” would require adding a final bit of extra facetiousness with a noun that goes with “donner”: Ma chère, vous avez besoin d’une leçon sur …/d’un cadeau d[e]… [’un changement d’attitude] et il/cela me fera plaisir de vous la/le donner.)

Comment: Merci! À mon avis c'est aussi une question du sociolecte; dans mon cas finalement le _changement d'attitude_ c'est très usuel avec _m'en occuper_ (mais je préfère le _m'en charger_ de cette [réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14099/3177)), alors que l'ajustement semblait étrange. Aussi, chercher [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attitude) "changement" pour la citation du général de Gaulle! Je pense qu'on a fait le tour avec les réponses. Merci encore!

Answer (score 3):

Effectivement, ton très littéral *ajustement d'attitude* sonnerait étrangement même si l'on en devine le sens.

Il y a toujours plusieurs possibilités pour ce genre d'exercice, mais je proposerais quelque chose comme :

> Ma chère, vous avez besoin d'un **petit**<sup>1</sup> **rappel à l'ordre**, et **je me ferai (un|le)<sup>2</sup> plaisir** de **m'en charger [personnellement]<sup>3</sup>**.

<sup>1</sup> *petit* a bien sûr ici un sens ironique, fréquent dans ce genre de formule faite pour impressionner.
<sup>2</sup> "un" est sans doute préférable, mais les deux s'entendent.
<sup>3</sup> petite touche d'emphase

Comment: @Amphiteoh What's an *attitude adjustment* to you ? Physical beating or disciplinary exchange/conversation ? If the latter, I'll go with *rappel à l'ordre* which is used in many different contexts. (And why the hell did I write that in english? oO)

Comment: Merci. re: [rappel à l'ordre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ordre). Bien à mon avis c'est pas binaire; si l'admonestation est intense et qu'il y a proximité, ça devient quelque chose de plus physique. Mais mon commentaire est davantage sur les sources/définitions dans la réponse, parce qu'ensuite on a des détails importants étayés en commentaire. Mais donc l'_admonestation_. Le contexte n'est pas tout étayé ici; le suite implique un divulgâcheur; c'est bien plus qu'à une admonestation qu'aura droit Julie ici mais j'aime bien le _rappel à l'ordre_; l'idée d'autorité.

Answer (score 2):

Je proposerais quelque chose dans le style

> Tu as besoin [d'un recadrement/d'être recadrée] ma chère, et je me ferai un plaisir de le faire

Il n'y a toujours pas le verbe "donner", mais je ne vois actuellement pas de formulation le permettant...

On parle de "**recadrer** quelqu'un" quand il a un comportement non toléré.
Par exemple un parent doit **recadrer** un enfant s'il fait régulièrement des caprices ou n'écoute pas ses parents, ou un patron qui va **recadrer** un employé s'il manque de sérieux au travail.
Ce terme image la notion de limites, c'est à dire que la personne qui doit être **recardée** dépasse les limites, et qu'il faut lui rappeler où elles sont.

Comment: Merci, donc ce serait directement basé sur l'idée au figuré du [_recadrage_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/recadrage) ? Comme je mentionnais dans le commentaire de l'autre réponse, je suis friand de détails sur le mot chois et son sens dans les réponses...

Comment: Je rajoute alors ces détails dans la réponse :)

Answer (score 2):

Essai de transposition :

Un peu soutenue, appliquée à un homme ; vous saurez trouvez les accords pour une dame (*Ma chère vous...* , ou un possible *Ma chérie tu...*) :

> Mon cher, vous avez besoin d'être remis à votre place, et j'aurai le plaisir de vous y conduire.

Très amical :

> Mon cher vous aller devoir vous adapter, et j'aurai le plaisir de vous y aider.